# Bulk Edit phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hey so I'm trying to change about a thousand records but only one column.

I want to update 'event ID' from 30 to 35 but only for records where 't_activity_date' is between 2018-01-01, 2018-12-01

So while I can search and get the records I want to display, I don't know how to bulk edit it. I know you can check all and do the edit function down the bottom but I think it's too many records to change this way as it just times out.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why not use SQL? Something like `UPDATE <table> SET <eventID> = 35 WHERE <eventID> = 30 AND t_activity_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-01'`?

Comment: thanks so much! I had something similar for SQL but wasn't sure if it'd be correct. doing it by current event ID is a better idea, will give that a go today :)